# Convert file from VOC to MP3

Tags: audio, mp3, portable, file-conversion

I would like to convert a sound file (from a digital voice recorder) with the extension `.voc` to an `.mp3` file or some other common sound files. I am on Windows 7 64 bit.

I have tried the program [voc2wav](http://www.partnersinrhyme.com/pc/pcConvert.shtml) but it gives me an error message saying that the program isn't 64 bit.

I need a solution that does not require installing software. (The voice recorder did come with a program that I could install, but I would like to avoid that).

Comment: What is wrong with installing a program?

Comment: @Moab There is nothing wrong with installing a program... I would like something that I could run of a USB drive. But if I don't find a standalone program, I will just have to install the software.

Comment: I bet the portable version of VLC can convert it...http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html

Comment: @Moab Ok, I will try that. I see that it is quite a huge program though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) should be able to read .voc files. You can use its built-in conversion feature (go to Media -> "Convert / Save..." or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to convert them to MP3s.

VLC Player is free and is available as a [portable version](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) that doesn't require installation, so seems to meet all your requirements.

Edit: in case your .voc files are in the RCA-VOC proprietary format, rather than the more common Creative Voice format, try [this online converter](http://dinhe.net/~aredridel/devoc/). Or if you want to be able to do it offline, get [devoc](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/rca/) (that the online converter is based on) to convert your .voc files to .wav, then use [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) to convert them to MP3s. Note, however, that devoc is 16-bit and thus won't run on 64-bit Windows.

Edit2: I compiled devoc to a 32-bit executable that runs on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. You can download it [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=2251e6d0ea58488a&resid=2251E6D0EA58488A!412&parid=2251E6D0EA58488A!138). I tested it with the sample .voc files posted on the devoc homepage and it converts them to .wav just fine.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, it doesn't seem to work. On http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html it looks like VLC doesn't support the .voc format... ?

Comment: @Thomas VLC does support .voc, it's listed as Creative Voice. However, your files seem to be in another, proprietary format that just happens to use the same file extension. See the edits in my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks a bunch for compiling the program! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

[Never used this but looks promising](http://www.pendriveapps.com/audiovideo-to-exe-converter/#more-3363)

Audio/Video to EXE Converter is a Portable Software that allows you to convert Audio and Video files from one format to another. The utility can be used as either a converter or player. In addition, you can create self playing executable files from your audio or video files. Audio to EXE, Video to EXE etc. You can play the resulting exe without a dedicated player and accompanying codec. It works standalone.

Audio Video to EXE

Supported conversion formats: 3gp, aac, ac3, aiff, asf, avi, exe, flac, flv, gif, m1v, m2v, m4v, mka, mkv, mov, mp2, mp3, mp4, mpc, mpg, nut, ogg, ra, rm, swf, vob, **voc**, wav, wma, wmv, wv, yuv

Comment: I just tried this on my files and it claims that it is an unknown format.... ?

Comment: It mat be a proprietary format of voc, you may have to use the software that came with the VR, or try VLC.

Comment: Thanks for the effort though. I did try the VLC and that also doesn't work. I am wondering if the format is really voc...

Comment: They can use any file extension they want, more than likely it is a proprietary file format that uses the voc file extension. See if mediainfo can tell what it is...http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/

Answer (score 1):

For converting offline you could also try to use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), As far as I know you can install additional codecs if you need to, I'm not sure if they support VOC out of the box, but they support pretty much anything.